HoTT universes (is it an axiom ?)
I just began to learn type theory and read HoTT.
In the book, it is said in chapter I that type theory presented here has no axioms and rather only rules. But a few pages later, cumulative universes are introduced and it look to me just as an axiom.
May a graceful soul point out to me what the interesting difference is ?

You have better chance of getting an answer if you write out (using MathJaX) what rules exactly you are referring to.

Also, I didn't check but I'm sure the HoTT book won't say type theory has no axioms. Most of the book literally works under the univalence axiom, so it probably said "very few axioms" and not none.

Thanks for your feedbacks ! I won’t forget them. Turns out that in this specific part of the book, the univalence axiom isn’t used.

In type theory, an axiom is usually taken to be a postulated term of some type. So it is a special kind of rule that says "there exists a symbol $t$ such that $t : A$". This is because under the reading of types as propositions, this introduces a symbol $t$ that represents "Here's a proof, stop asking questions".
A rule of the form $\mathcal U_i : \mathcal U_j$ is not an axiom, because the term $\mathcal U_i$ already has a meaning on its own, and we are only assigning a new type to it. You can regard it as an axiom, if you are looking at a type theory as a structure (like how a group is a structure) instead of a logic (like first order logic). But this would make things more confusing/ambiguous.

Manu thanks for your answer ! Still something is bothering me. Would you agree that the existence of the $\mathcal{U}_i$’s is an axiom ? Why would there be any type in the first place ? Who are them ? Furthermore, why wouldn’t $\mathcal{U}_1=\mathcal{U}_2$ (how to avoid Russel like paradoxes ?) ? Don’t you need axioms on those cumulative types ?

@Maxime Answering these one by one. (1) No, this is a rule. In first order logic, the existence of the conjunction operation is also not an axiom, only things like $p \wedge q \to p$ are considered axioms. (2) (3) The types are specified by the rules, although I don't encourage you to look them up at your first readthrough, do it after you second or third readthrough. (4) This wouldn't happen because we can guarantee that $\mathcal{U}_1 = \mathcal{U}_2$ cannot be derived from the rules, how exactly is too long for a comment. (5) No.

Brilliant ! I think I’m begging to get it. Have a beautiful day !
